# how to get my 2x2 subplots to be square in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I need to make these 2x2 subplots square while still having them share the same axis and without changing the axis bounds. I really do not want to have to move my legend or change the range of my axis if I do not have to.

Here is my code:

```
fig, ((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4)) = plt.pyplot.subplots(2, 2, sharex = True)
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0, wspace = 0)
plt.pyplot.subplots_adjust(right=.8, top=.8)
ax1.grid()
ax2.grid()
ax3.grid()
ax4.grid()
ax1.scatter(p1, q1, marker = 's', color = 'royalblue', alpha = 0.5, label = 'Saintonage et al. 2017')
ax1.scatter(p33, q33, marker = 's', color = 'rebeccapurple', alpha = 0.5)
ax3.grid()
ax1.plot(x000, func6(x000), color ='k')
ax1.xaxis.grid(True, which='minor')
ax2.xaxis.grid(True, which='minor')
ax3.xaxis.grid(True, which='minor')
ax4.xaxis.grid(True, which='minor')
ax1.scatter(p2, q2, marker = 's', color = 'seagreen', alpha = 0.5, label = 'Saintonage et al. 2017')
ax1.scatter(p3, q3, marker ='s', color = 'maroon', alpha = 0.5, label = 'Saintonage et al. 2017')
ax1.set_ylim([-1.2, 2.2])
ax2.scatter(p4, q4, marker = 'o', color = 'royalblue', alpha = 0.75)
ax2.scatter(p30, q30, marker = 'o', color = 'rebeccapurple', alpha = 0.75)
ax2.plot(x0, func1(x0), color ='k')
ax2.scatter(p5, q5, marker = 'o', color = 'seagreen', alpha = 0.75)
ax2.set_ylim([-1.2, 2.2])
ax2.set_xlim([9.8, 11.7])
ax3.scatter(p7, q7, marker = 'D', color = 'royalblue', alpha = 0.75)
ax3.plot(x00, func2(x00), color = 'k')
upperlimit = np.array([1], dtype = bool)
ax4.scatter(lmassg, lsfrg, marker = 'd', color = 'maroon')  
ax3.set_ylim([0, 3.5])
ax4.plot(x000, func(x000), color ='k')
ax4.set_ylim([0, 3.5])
fig.legend(handles = legend_elements, numpoints = 1, loc = (.77, .3), ncol=1, fontsize = 8 )
ax1.tick_params(axis='both', labelsize=10)
ax1.tick_params(axis='both', labelsize=12)
ax2.tick_params(axis='both', labelsize=10)
ax2.tick_params(axis='both',  labelsize=2)
ax3.tick_params(axis='both', labelsize=12)
ax3.tick_params(axis='both', labelsize=12)
ax4.tick_params(axis='both', labelsize=12)
ax4.tick_params(axis='y', labelsize=2)
```

Here is my plot:
[image: plot]

Comment: This will get a lot easier in the future with the [`box_aspect`](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/axes_box_aspect.html). But for now you will have to either use the axes_grid1 toolkit, or calculate the required subplot parameters (left, right, bottom, top) under the constraint that you want square subplots.

Comment: For the latter, you essentially have `figwidth*(right-left)=2*axsize` and `figheight*(top-bottom) = 2*axsize`. So `figwdth/figheight = (top-bottom)/(right-left)`. Set the values such that this equation holds.